# ArrayList concurrent access

Tags: java, arraylist, concurrency

I am aware that `ArrayList` is not thread safe, but I'm unsure about the exact implications of this.

In the case of `ThreadA` and `ThreadB` both using an `ArrayList`, which of these situations will cause issues and necessitate synchronization?

1. Both threads simultaneously reading the same index
2. `ThreadA` replacing an element which `ThreadB` is attempting to access simultaneously, assuming that you don't care whether or not `ThreadB` gets the old or the new element.

Comment: By "accessing the same index" do you mean reading, writing, or both?

Comment: Thread safety usually implies write operations, and change of states. If both thread just use the list for reading, you are fine.

Comment: "You don't care whether `ThreadB` gets the old or new element." What if `ThreadB` gets a little bit of both? Would that be problematic?

Comment: @BilltheLizard there, edited it for clarity

Comment: @Heuster yes, that would be problematic!

Comment: @Thread unsafe means anything can happen. Getting old or new element is already a weaker form of thread safety known as `regularity`

Comment: @UmNyobe Interesting - is there perhaps a java list which is not as slow as `Vector` but which has `regularity`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Both threads simultaneously reading the same index

It is okay for multiple threads to be reading from  common `ArrayList` *if* the list was constructed by the thread that forked the `ThreadA` and `ThreadB` and the list is fully constructed and loaded before the threads were forked.

The reason for this is that there is a happens-before guarantee with a thread and the memory of the thread that forked it.  If, for example, `ThreadC` builds the `ArrayList` but *after* `ThreadA` and `ThreadB` are forked, then there is no guarantee that A and B will fully see the `ArrayList` -- if at all.

If this is not the case then you will need to synchronize the list.  See below.

> ThreadA changing an element which ThreadB is attempting to access simultaneously, assuming that you don't care whether or not ThreadB gets the old or the new element.

Once you talk about modifications to the list in a concurrent setting, then you must synchronize on that list otherwise there is no guarantee that the modifications will be published and there are chances that the list could be partially published which could cause data exceptions.  As @Marko puts it, its internal state may be inconsistent.

You can either use a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` which is designed for few updates and many reads, use `Collections.synchronizedList(...)` to make your list be protected, you can access the list always in a `synchronized` block (for all writes *and* reads), or you can switch to using a concurrent collection such as `ConcurrentSkipList` or something.

> ThreadA changing an element which ThreadB is attempting to access simultaneously

This is somewhat ambiguous.  If you are talking about, for example, storing objects in the list and then changing the objects that happen to be stored in the list then you are not going to have a synchronization problem on the *list* but you will have a synchronization problem with the *object*.  If the list's data is not changing then it will be fine.  However, if you need to protect the object then either a list of `AtomicReference<YourObject>`, `volatile` fields in the object, or other synchronization is required to make sure the changes are published between the threads.

Comment: Why does it matter whether the list was constructed and fully formed before forking of the threads?

Comment: I've added details about this to my answer @s1ice.  It's about the happens-before guarantee with one thread forking another.

Comment: nice to know! Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity in my #2, I cleared it up.

Answer (score 2):

In your question I see an emphasis on *simultaneous* access.

The issues with concurrent access have very little to do with simultaneity. To put it more strongly, even if you ensure no simultaneous access happens, you are still a long way from a thread-safe program.

Answers to your specific points:

> 1) Both threads simultaneously reading the same index

As long as your threads only read and never write, you are safe regardless of simultaneity.

> 2) `ThreadA` changing an element which `ThreadB` is attempting to access simultaneously, assuming that you don't care whether or not `ThreadB` gets the old or the new element.

Whether or not writing happens at the same time as reading, you are in trouble. You are not just in danger of seeing stale values; you can see a completely broken `List` object (its internal state is inconsistent).

If any thread changes the list, you need synchronization.

For more information I strongly advise getting acquainted with the Java Memory Model, preferrably from the corresponding section in the Java Language Specification.

Comment: *"As long as your threads only read and never write, you are safe regardless of simultaneity."* - provide the list was safely published in the first place and hasn't been changed by a 3rd thread since.

Comment: There's no "3rd thread" in the question :) The sentence that actually needs qualification is this one: "If any thread changes the list, you need synchronization." because it doesn't apply if the thread which changes the list does it before the reading threads come to life.

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize the list prior to publishing it, there's no problem with having multiple threads reading from the list.

As soon as you are reading and writing to the list concurrently, you need to synchronize access to it.

Comment: So do you disagree with 2. in the answer Andres posted?

Comment: Yes, 2. is bad. If you don't care about `ThreadB` seeing an old copy of the list you might consider [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)

Comment: +1 To be more specific.  If you initialize the list in the same thread that then forks the two threads that are doing the reading then you are fine.

Comment: But suppose ThreadA is creating new object and then writes it at given index. ThradB then will read this index (at any time), also ThreadB will not modify List. I suppose it is possible to make it safe. I think keeping references as AtomicReference-s would be recomended.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand you. If you have mutable objects inside your list, you can mutate them without affecting the thread safety of the list (you may hit other concurrency issues though). You can not add() remove() or set() items in an ArrayList concurrently.